Brezis Functional Analysis Exercise 1.14: Item 1
Let $E =\ell^1$ and consider the two sets
$$
X = \{x=(x_n)_{n\ge 1} \in E ; x_{2n}=0 \forall n\ge 1 \}
$$
and
$$
Y = \{y=(y_n)_{n\ge 1} \in E ; y_{2n}=\frac{1}{2^n}y_{2n-1} \forall n\ge 1 \}.
$$
Check that $\overline{X+Y} = E$.
I saw a solution that for any $a\in E$, considered the sequence
$$
z^m = \Big(\dots, 0,\underbrace{\frac{a_{2n}}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\big)^k}_{2n^{th} \ \mathrm{term}},0, \dots \Big).
$$
The claim was that this sequence is in $X+Y$. But I don't see how this can be true since you would have a term like
$$
y^m = \Big( \dots, a_{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\big)^k ,\underbrace{\frac{a_{2n}}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\big)^k}_{2n^{th}},\dots \Big)
$$
has finite $\ell^1$ norm, and the odd terms look something like $2^n a_{2n}$ when $m$ is large. Am I missing something or do we need to use another approach?

Let $\{\delta_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ denote the standard basis in $\ell^1.$ The space $X$ contains $\delta_{2n-1}$ for all $n,$ while $Y$ contains $\delta_{2n}+{2^n}\delta_{2n-1}$ for all $n.$ Therefore for all $n$ the space $X+Y$ contains $\delta_{2n-1}$ and also $\delta_{2n}$ as $$\delta_{2n}=\left (\delta_{2n}+{2^n}\delta_{2n-1}\right )-  { 2^n}\delta_{2n-1}$$ Summarizing $X+Y$ contains all finite linear combinations of $\{\delta_n\}_{n=1}^\infty.$ Hence it is dense in $\ell^1.$

I'll give a different solution, which I think is pretty clear.
The finitely supported sequences, namely  sequences which are zero except for a finite number of entries, are dense in $\ell^1$. We show that every such sequence is in $X+Y$.
Pick a finitely supported  sequence $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots)$. Then there exists  $N\in {\mathbb N}$ such that $0=v_{N}=v_{N+1}=v_{N+2} = \dots$.  Next let's find $y\in Y$ such that $y_{2n} = v_{2n}$ for all $n$. Since we must have  $y_{2n} = 2^{-n} y_{2n-1}$, it follows that $y_{2n-1} = 2^n y_{2n} = 2^n v_{2n}$ for all $n$, and therefore $y$ is uniquely determined:
$$y= (y_1,y_2,\dots) = (2v_2,v_2,4v_4,v_4,8v_6,v_6,\dots).$$
Of course, $y$ is also finitely supported, which implies it is in $\ell^1$, and so $y \in Y$.
Next, let $x= v- y$. Then by construction
$$x= (v_1-y_1,0,v_3-y_3,0,v_5-y_5,0,\dots)=(v_1-2v_2,0,v_3-4v_4,0,v_5-8v_6,0,\dots)\in X.$$
We proved that for any finite supported sequence $v$,  $v= x+y$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.
That's it. Specifically for the unit vector $e_k=(0,\dots,1,0,\dots)$ where the $1$ is in the $k$-th entry, we have

$e_{2n-1}$ is clearly in $X$, so it is in $X+Y$.
If $v=e_{2n}$ then our solution gives $e_{2n}=x+y$ where $Y\ni y= (\underset{2^n-2}{\underbrace{0,\dots,0}},2^n,1,0,\dots)$, and $X\ni x=(0,\dots,0,-2^n,0,\dots)$.

